# Print return value in Java

Tags: java, return-value

I'm currently making a high-low guessing game in Java. I believe I have two issues hindering the game from functioning properly.

Firstly, I have a while-statement inside the *playGame* method that doesn't change as it is now, and I have trouble understanding how I can make it change if the correct guess is made. As I understand it I can't change the value of *boolean bool = true;* from the giveResponse method, it has to be done from the same method *playGame*? If there a better way of doing this than using a while-statement?

Secondly, when the correct guess is made and the *playGame* method return the value of parameter *guessCount* to the main method it should then be printed out. The instruction I have for this game says it should be printed in the main method after the return have been made.

```
import java.io.Reader;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class HiLo2 {
 public static void main(String[] args) {

  System.out.println("Decide a level of difficulty\r"
    + "1. 1-10 \r"
    + "2. 1-100 \r"
    + "3. 1-1000");

  Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
  int n = reader.nextInt();

   if (n==1) {
             playGame(10);
   }
         else if (n==2) {
             playGame(100);
         }
         else if (n==3) {
          playGame(1000);
         }
         else {
          System.out.println("This level of difficulty doesn't exist. Please try one between 1 and 3.");
         }
  }

 public static int playGame(int maxNumber) {
  int answer = (int)(Math.random() * maxNumber) +1;
  int guessCount = 0;
  boolean bool = true;
  Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("Guess a number between 1 and " + maxNumber);

  while (bool) { 
  int guess = reader.nextInt();
  guessCount = guessCount + 1;
  giveResponse(answer, guess);
  }

  return guessCount;
 }

 public static void giveResponse(int answer, int guess) {  
  if (guess == answer) {
   System.out.println("Your guess is correct!\r");
  }
  else if (guess > answer) {
   System.out.println("Your guess is too high, guess again:\r");
  }
  else if (guess < answer) {
   System.out.println("Your guess is too low, guess again:\r");
  }
 }
}
```

I hope the questions are clear and specific enough. Any pointers in the right direction is appreciated.

Comment: Never write while (true). You'll create an infinite loop and render your program useless. Rather find a way to capture your input from the user. Then validate that input. If the input is valid, then choose the level else return a message that prompts for a valid input. As a bonus, offer the user a quit option like "press 'q' to exit the game" and add that to your validation to. The rest should be straightforward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could have the giveResponse method return a boolean

```
static boolean giveResponse(...)
```

and put `return false;` inside the `if (guess == answer){` case, and `return true` at the end of the method. Instead of calling `giveResponse` as a void method, use `bool = giveResponse(answer,guess)`.

And for the second question, add a int numberOfGuesses in the main method before the if statement, and call playGame with numberOfGuesses = playGame(...), then System.out.println("You guessed " + numberOfGuesses + " times."); after the if-statements.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're trying to do.

```
public class HiLo2 {
 public static void main(String[] args) {

  System.out.println("Decide a level of difficulty\r"
    + "1. 1-10 \r"
    + "2. 1-100 \r"
    + "3. 1-1000");

  Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
  int n = reader.nextInt();

   if (n==1) {
             System.out.println("Guess count: "+playGame(10));
   }
         else if (n==2) {
             System.out.println("Guess count: "+playGame(100));
         }
         else if (n==3) {
          System.out.println("Guess count: "+playGame(1000));
         }
         else {
          System.out.println("This level of difficulty doesn't exist. Please try one between 1 and 3.");
         }
  }

 public static int playGame(int maxNumber) {
  int answer = (int)(Math.random() * maxNumber) +1;
  int guessCount = 0;
  boolean bool = false;
  Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("Guess a number between 1 and " + maxNumber);

  while (! bool) { 
  int guess = reader.nextInt();
  guessCount = guessCount + 1;
  bool = giveResponse(answer, guess);
  }

  return guessCount;
 }

 public static boolean giveResponse(int answer, int guess) {  
  if (guess == answer) {
   System.out.println("Your guess is correct!\r");
   return true;
  }
  else if (guess > answer) {
   System.out.println("Your guess is too high, guess again:\r");
   return false;
  }
  else if (guess < answer) {
   System.out.println("Your guess is too low, guess again:\r");
   return false;
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your complete solution

```
import java.io.Reader;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HereSOl {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Decide a level of difficulty\r" + "1. 1-10 \r" + "2. 1-100 \r" + "3. 1-1000");
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = reader.nextInt();

        if (n == 1) {
            System.out.println("Guesstcount : " + playGame(10));
        } else if (n == 2) {
            System.out.println("Guesstcount : " + playGame(100));           
        } else if (n == 3) {
            System.out.println("Guesstcount : " + playGame(1000));          
        } else {
            System.out.println("This level of difficulty doesn't exist. Please try one between 1 and 3.");
        }
    }

    public static int playGame(int maxNumber) {
        int answer = (int) (Math.random() * maxNumber) + 1;
        int guessCount = 0;
        boolean bool = true;
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Guess a number between 1 and " + maxNumber);

        while (bool) {
            int guess = reader.nextInt();
            guessCount = guessCount + 1;
            boolean ans =giveResponse(answer, guess); 
            if (ans == true) {              
                break;
            }
        }

        return guessCount;
    }

    public static boolean giveResponse(int answer, int guess) {
        if (guess == answer) {
            System.out.println("Your guess is correct!\r");
            return true;
        } else if (guess > answer) {
            System.out.println("Your guess is too high, guess again:\r");
            return false;
        } else if (guess < answer) {
            System.out.println("Your guess is too low, guess again:\r");
            return false;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use **enum**, Here is my Solution.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HiLo2 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Decide a level of difficulty\r" + "1. 1-10 \r" + "2. 1-100 \r" + "3. 1-1000");

    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = reader.nextInt();

    if (n == 1) {
      playGame(10);
    } else if (n == 2) {
      playGame(100);
    } else if (n == 3) {
      playGame(1000);
    } else {
      System.out.println("This level of difficulty doesn't exist. Please try one between 1 and 3.");
    }
  }
  public static int playGame(int maxNumber) { 
    int answer = (int) (Math.random() * maxNumber) + 1;
    int guessCount = 0;
    boolean bool = true;
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Guess a number between 1 and " + maxNumber);
    while (bool) {
      int guess = reader.nextInt();
      guessCount = guessCount + 1;
      Answer ans = giveResponse(answer, guess);
      System.out.println(ans.getMessage());
      if (ans == Answer.CORRECT) {
        bool = false;
        System.out.println("You took " + guessCount + " guess to get right number.");
      }
    }
    return guessCount;
  }

  public static Answer giveResponse(int answer, int guess) {
    if (guess == answer) {
      return Answer.CORRECT;
    } else if (guess > answer) {
      return Answer.HIGH;
    } else {
      return Answer.LOW;
    }
  }

  private enum Answer {
    CORRECT("Your guess is correct!\r"), HIGH("Your guess is too high, guess again:\r"), LOW("Your guess is too low, guess again:\r");

    private String message;

    public String getMessage() {
      return this.message;
    }
    Answer(String message) {
      this.message = message;
    }
  }
}
```